# WCF Service authentication and authorization

Tags: c#, wcf, authorization, wcf-security

I have the requirement to setup authentication and authorization on a WCF Service, right now the service is created and working but no authentication.

There is also the need to authenticate existing users and passwords that are being stored in a SQL database and are already used by another web application, but since I do not have the source code for it, and being still adjusting do .NET I am having some dificulties.

I can read the database and found several aspnet_ tables in the database such as aspnet_Users, aspnet_Roles etc that so far seem to match with the ones used in the web application.

My question is how can I easily implement authentication and method authorization using the existing database.

Please note that I do not have access to the web-application source code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC uses the standard ASP.Net membership provider. If you click the Log On button/register link - you can add a user. ASP.Net will create App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF containing the membership information.  You can move ASPNETDB.MDF to a remote DB server, but you must use the Membership provider schema/DB (unless you write your own provider).

A few MVC links to get you started.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-vb
http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2007/11/25/asp-net-mvc-framework-security.aspx
http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-securing-your-controller-actions/

The default authentication/authorization configuration added use ASP.NET standard membership and role manager service provider( the local SQL Express one).  If your existing database(for user login) is also ASP.NET standard sql membership database, you can simply change the connection string of the membership section. Otherwise, you might need to create a custom membership provider which uses your own database tables for user authentication.

**Implementing a Membership Provider**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

**Building Custom Providers for ASP.NET 2.0 Membership**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Really no easy way to achieve your requirements. [Here](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/) is the library you can use and follow stricktly steps described in this [blog](http://revweblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/custom-basic-authentication-for-iis7/) to setup authentication with SQL Membership provider for WCF services.
In my case I did small update to the library. I've commented out line of code

```
//if (!IsAnonymousAllowed)
```